# I'm stuck at ubuntu login loop?

Tags: tty

I'm able to enter desktop menu only through **sudo systemctl restart gdm3** command. Is there any option to disable tty1 from here, because It will happen again when I will switch on.

Comment: Why do you believe that disabling tty1 is the appropriate action here? what is the output of `systemctl get-default`?

Comment: Unclear. What is the "desktop menu"? What happens at first when you boot? Do you end up in a terminal? etc. Be specific if you want specific help.

Comment: I'm not an expert in linux. So I don't know the specific terms but I'll try to describe the problem. I was using kde plasma environment which I tried to remove using synaptic package manager and it is very likely that some of ubuntu package got removed too. Now whenever I try to login I'm stuck at login loop. After some googling I was able to connect to internet did some suggested things which let me enter the normal login screen through "sudo systemctl restart gdm3" command. Now my question is that can I fix login loop problem? Disabling tty1 was just a thought.

Comment: It sounds like you broke your system by uninstalling the desktop environment, if reinstalling the DE doesn't fix it, you're probably better off reinstalling the entire OS.  If you want to troubleshoot this further you really should provide more detailed information about what you did that broke your system as well as all of these things that you've tried since it happened. Some of these ideas, like disabling tty, sound like you may only be making the problem worse by creating new problems. If you give a command, Ubuntu will obey even if the command wrecks your system...

Comment: A DE is comprised of dozens of packages. You can't just simply install and uninstall desktop environments at your leisure.  That's a quick way to break your system. Changing the DE is a messy task for advanced users, this is why Ubuntu comes in so many official flavors so you can install the DE that you want from the very start.  You can also "test drive" different DEs by live booting installation media for the different flavors, without affecting an installed system.